# Mink/behat file attach

Tags: php, behat, mink, sahi

I am using behat/mink/sahi. I am trying to attach file to an input type element using the xpath because i can not locate it with the normal function that behat already has. My full_path is already in the behat.yml file

```
   /**
     * @When I attach file
     */
    public function iAttachFile()
    {
        $page = $this->getSession()->getPage();
        $element = $page->find('xpath', "//input[@data-field-type='logo']");
        $element->attachFile('full_path');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`attachFile` doesn't know to get the `full_path` from behat.yml alone.

Make sure you have the latest `"behat/mink-selenium2-driver"` or this PR https://github.com/minkphp/MinkSelenium2Driver/pull/252 to work for remote hosts.

In my case I have a path under `Behat\MinkExtension:` the following `files_path: %paths.base%/features/bootstrap` and after this copy your file in `bootstrap`

And for full path I use something like this:

```
$path = $this->getMinkParameter('files_path').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. $file_name;
$element->attachFile($path);
```

As a best practice you should keep your file in the automation project.
`var_dump` your path, if is correct it should work when running local, for remote you need that PR to upload file to the selenium instance.

Comment: Please provide an example of the given path if possible.

Comment: I update my composer with mink-selenium2-driver , var dump the path but still nothing uploads. The var dump gave me output  "string(1) '/' " in the console but no change.